# b-table do boostrap do vue

Tags: vue.js

Estou usando o `b-table` do *Bootstrap* do *Vue*.

Tenho um objeto nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a tabela está populando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está jogando o objeto inteiro dentro do campo, como conseguimos ver nesses campos circulados, mas eu gostaria de conseguir escolher os itens a serem exibidos como nos campos com seta. 
Como eu faço para acessar os niveis do objeto?

Código para criar a table:

```html
<div class="driver-admin">
    <b-table hover striped :items="drivers"></b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: É que nesse teu objeto, tem um um outro objeto dentro dele e um array. Por isso dica desse jeito. O Address e o Document tem que tratar de um jeito diferente, por exemplo, ser apenas outros campos normais no objeto (como state e city).

Answer (score 0):

segundo a documentação, vc pode usar a props   fields. No componente vc colocaria :fields="fields" e ai na data do componente vc popula o `fields` com um array que contem uma lista dos nomes dos campos que voce quer trazer..

[Link da documentacao](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#fields-as-a-simple-array)